# How to set the 32nd bit of a Java integer without messing up its printed string representation

Tags: java, integer, unsigned, signed

I'm trying to write code that will let me print out the value of the data field of CAN messages as a series of shorts in hex form. CAN message data fields contain 4 shorts, so for instance, I might print out one message as "FFFF EEEE ABAB 2013".

I can encode 2 shorts of a CAN message in an integer value, and everything works fine so long as the 32nd bit of the integer isn't set. Because Java uses signed integers, setting the 32nd bit causes it to print out a series of "f"s. What I want is the integer to act as an unsigned value, so that printing it out doesn't cause problems.

Here is an example of it going wrong:

```
(int value): 0x80000000
(string rep short 1): 0xffff8000
<crash>
```

And here is how it works in every other case:

```
(int value): 0x40000000
(string rep short 1): 0x4000
(string rep short 2): 0x0
```

The code where I try to represent the CAN message data and where the crash occurs:

```
public String getFormattedData() {
    String dataString = "";

    for(String aShort : Utility.splitStringByWhitespace(getData())) {
        try{
            dataString += ("0000".substring(0, 4 - aShort.length()) + aShort) + " ";
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(getData());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    return dataString.toUpperCase();
}
```

Specifically, the crash occurs because the "f"s bump the length of the short's string representation to 8 characters, so "4 - aShort.length()" will yield a negative value, which is invalid.

Edit: For those asking, in this particular case this is how I'm using integers to encode the data before I convert it to a string representation:

```
public String convertToCANMessageData(PWMChannel channel) {
    int channelVal = channel.getValue();
    int entryDataHI = 0, entryDataLO = 0;

    entryDataHI += channelVal << 24;
    entryDataHI += smallData << 8;
    entryDataHI += (largeData >> 8) & 0xFF;
    entryDataLO += (largeData & 0xFF) << 24;

    if(ramping) {
        entryDataHI = entryDataHI | (1 << 16);
    } else {
        entryDataHI = entryDataHI & ~(1 << 16);
    }

    if(jumping) {
        entryDataHI = entryDataHI | (1 << 17);
    } else {
        entryDataHI = entryDataHI & ~(1 << 17);
    }

    if(frequencySetting) {
        entryDataHI = entryDataHI | (1 << 18);
    } else {
        entryDataHI = entryDataHI & ~(1 << 18);
    }

    return String.format("%x %x %x %x", entryDataHI >> 16, entryDataHI & 0xFFFF,
                            entryDataLO >> 16, entryDataLO & 0xFFFF);
}
```

Comment: Where do you convert between numbers and strings? All I see is a lot of string processing.

Comment: What about using a long instead an int? It's big enough to avoid sign problems and you only need to remove leading 0s

Comment: @Pablo, I tried it with longs as well, but what happened was I got something like 0xffffffffffffd000 in place of 0xffffd000.

Comment: I see the problem now. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, to set the 32nd bit of an `int` you can use the bitwise OR operator:

```
myInteger |= (1 << 31);
```

If you don't want this to "mess up" the string representation, that's an issue of how you convert the integer into string. For example the `Integer.toHexString` method treats ints as unsigned:

```
print(Integer.toHexString(-3)); // output: fffffffd
```

**UPDATE:** Use the unsigned left shift `>>>` when formatting numbers: The regular left shift `>>` extends the sign bit, so that a left shift of a negative number stays negative and doesn't "suddenly" become a huge positive number.

```
return String.format("%x %x %x %x", entryDataHI >>> 16, entryDataHI & 0xFFFF,
                        entryDataLO >>> 16, entryDataLO & 0xFFFF);
```

Alternatively you can use masking which you already seem to be familiar with:

```
return String.format("%x %x %x %x", (entryDataHI >> 16) & 0xFFFF, entryDataHI & 0xFFFF,
                        (entryDataLO >> 16) & 0xFFFF, entryDataLO & 0xFFFF);
```

Comment: It doesn't treat them as unsigned. FFFFFFFD is -3.

Comment: FFFFFFFD base 16 is 4294967293 base 10. -3 base 10 is -3 base 16.

Comment: FFFFFFFD is 4294967293 in base 10 if you treat it as unsigned. If you treat it as signed it's -3. -3 in two's complement in base 16 is FFFFFFFD.

Comment: No. In two's complement (more precisely, in 2-adic numbers), -3 is ...FFD, with an infinite string of 1-bits extending to the left. If you are limited to working with a finite number of bits, like with 32-bit numbers, you may cut the infinite bit-string to the right-most 32 bits so that -3 is represented as FFFFFFFD, but in the general setting FFFFFFFD is still 4294967293.

Comment: +1 and accepted for a very detailed answer. I wasn't aware of the triple-arrow operator before, cheers. I suppose that's the difference between arithmetic and logical bitwise shifting.

Answer (score 1):

Just use unsigned bitshift to get top half of the integer.

```
int i = 0x80000000;
short s = (short)(i >>> 16);
s is 0x8000
```

Comment: The problem here is that I'm storing the integer as a string and then trying to get an integer back from it. The string representation of 0x80000000 is "ffff8000", and I get a NumberFormatException trying to parse that back to an integer: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ffffd000"

Comment: Unless what you're saying I do is save my values as shorts before converting them to strings, and then converting them back to shorts, but that will involve a fair deal of re-write. Thanks all the same though.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem for now by adding a utility function:

```
public static int parseShort(String aShort) {
    if(aShort.length() > 4) aShort = aShort.substring(aShort.length()-4);

    return Integer.parseInt(aShort, 16);
}
```

If anyone's got a better solution, I'd be happy to mark their answer as accepted and try that out instead.